# How to write equation of linear regression with categorical predictors

Tags: r, lm

The output for the `lm` model with two categorical variables is:

```
Call:
lm(formula = exit_irr ~ type_exit + domicile, data = pe1)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.73013 -0.17926 -0.05142  0.03945  2.85043 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)          0.05333    0.22282   0.239  0.81101   
type_exitTrade Sale -0.11871    0.05469  -2.171  0.03081

type_exitUnlisted   -0.21208    0.07536  -2.814  0.00525 

domicileKSA          0.14593    0.22852   0.639  0.52363  

domicileKuwait       0.14679    0.22847   0.643  0.52108   

domicileOM           0.08708    0.28225   0.309  0.75791   

domicileUAE          0.18623    0.22808   0.817  0.41491   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3859 on 274 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.04221,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02124 
F-statistic: 2.013 on 6 and 274 DF,  p-value: 0.06415
```

How to write equation of linear regression with categorical predictors?

Comment: Google "treatment contrasts".

Answer (score 1):

the function `lm()` in r automatically accounts for categorical variables. It produces dummy variables of your categorical variables and does regression on it. Make sure your Categorical variables are of class factor. This can be done as:

```
pe1$type_exit <- as.factor(pe1$type_exit)
pe1$domicile  <- as.factor(pe1$domicile)
```

I have considered `type_exit` and `domicile` tobe your categorical columns.

Comment: Yes they are named as factors only. Can you pls help in the equation? As every category of single var has constants. So how will my equation look ?

Comment: if the combination is Trade Sale and OM. The equation would be                     0.05333 - 1 * 0.11871 + 1 * 0.08708. Similarly find for other combinations. You can always predict the values using the predict() base function in r. check ?predict in r

Comment: So which means I cannot make a equation as we make in normal regression. Like domicile has 5 levels, Bah being the base. and it does not have a coeeficient. so how will equation look like:

Comment: Levels of the factors take in the values of 1 and 0. 1 implies that the variable corresponds to that level and 0 represents not (some other level). if all the levels of domicile takes 0 take level is Bah. All the levels in your categorical variable are separate variables with the levels 0 and 1. This is how Dummy Coding works. I advice you to read Dummy Coding and accept this as answer to the question if it satisfied you.

Comment: http://www.psychstat.missouristate.edu/multibook/mlt08m.html This is a good place to start.